# Необходимо получить разершение рабочей области экрана средствами C++ и линукс

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Какими средствами мы можем получить размеры активной области экрана? схожий функционал есть у команды `wmctrl -d`.

Comment: wth `mctrl`?...

Comment: @Fat-Zer wmctrl -d*

Comment: Хм... А я тут xrandr мучал

Comment: @eri В некоторых источниках пишут, что Xrandr подключается к Х серверу, а тот в свою очередь ничего не знает о панелях интерфейса....

Comment: естественно не знает) у меня там заклинание с bc

Comment: @eri Что за bc??

Comment: калькулятор же. на самом деле я просто сделал всем своим пользователям одинаковые панели в стиле Виндовс ХР и просто вычитаю 24 из высоты экрана.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В пакете    x11-utils есть

```
xprop -root
```

Вывод

```
_GTK_WORKAREAS_D2(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 1920, 1080, 1920, 27, 1920, 1053
_GTK_WORKAREAS_D1(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 1920, 1080, 1920, 27, 1920, 1053
RESOURCE_MANAGER(STRING) = "Xft.dpi:\t96\nXft.antialias:\t1\nXft.hinting:\t1\nXft.hintstyle:\thintfull\nXft.rgba:\trgb\nXcursor.size:\t24\nXcursor.theme:\tAdwaita\n"
_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW): window id # 0x240000a
_NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING(WINDOW): window id # 0x1e0000c, 0x3a0000e, 0x2600001, 0x5600007, 0x580000f, 0x4200007, 0x2c00001, 0x240000a
_NET_CLIENT_LIST(WINDOW): window id # 0x1e0000c, 0x2c00001, 0x240000a, 0x3a0000e, 0x2600001, 0x4200007, 0x5600007, 0x580000f
_NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
PULSE_COOKIE(STRING) = "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"
PULSE_SERVER(STRING) = "{f525494e44dd4043999d315da17acbde}unix:/run/user/1000/pulse/native tcp:eri-macro:4713 tcp6:eri-macro:4713"
PULSE_ID(STRING) = "1000@f525494e44dd4043999d315da17acbde/962"
_NET_WORKAREA(CARDINAL) = 0, 27, 3840, 1053, 0, 27, 3840, 1053
_GTK_WORKAREAS_D0(CARDINAL) = 0, 0, 1920, 1080, 1920, 27, 1920, 1053
_NET_DESKTOP_NAMES(UTF8_STRING) = "Рабочее место 1"
_NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP(CARDINAL) = 0
_NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS(CARDINAL) = 2
_NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY(CARDINAL) = 3840, 1080
_NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT(CARDINAL) = 0, 0
_NET_SUPPORTING_WM_CHECK(WINDOW): window id # 0x400006
_NET_SUPPORTED(ATOM) = _NET_WM_NAME, _NET_CLOSE_WINDOW, _NET_WM_STATE, _NET_WM_STATE_SHADED, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_HORZ, _NET_WM_STATE_MAXIMIZED_VERT, _NET_WM_DESKTOP, _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS, _NET_CURRENT_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DOCK, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_TOOLBAR, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_MENU, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_UTILITY, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_SPLASH, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DIALOG, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DROPDOWN_MENU, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_POPUP_MENU, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_TOOLTIP, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NOTIFICATION, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_COMBO, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_DND, _NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE_NORMAL, _NET_WM_STATE_MODAL, _NET_CLIENT_LIST, _NET_CLIENT_LIST_STACKING, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR, _NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_PAGER, _NET_WM_ICON, _NET_WM_ICON_GEOMETRY, _NET_WM_MOVERESIZE, _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW, _NET_WM_STRUT, _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN, _NET_WM_STATE_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_PING, _NET_WM_PID, _NET_WORKAREA, _NET_SHOWING_DESKTOP, _NET_DESKTOP_LAYOUT, _NET_DESKTOP_NAMES, _NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS, _NET_WM_ACTION_MOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE, _NET_WM_ACTION_SHADE, _NET_WM_ACTION_STICK, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_HORZ, _NET_WM_ACTION_MAXIMIZE_VERT, _NET_WM_ACTION_CHANGE_DESKTOP, _NET_WM_ACTION_CLOSE, _NET_WM_STATE_ABOVE, _NET_WM_STATE_BELOW, _NET_STARTUP_ID, _NET_WM_STRUT_PARTIAL, _NET_WM_ACTION_FULLSCREEN, _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE, _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS, _NET_REQUEST_FRAME_EXTENTS, _NET_WM_USER_TIME, _NET_WM_STATE_DEMANDS_ATTENTION, _NET_MOVERESIZE_WINDOW, _NET_DESKTOP_GEOMETRY, _NET_DESKTOP_VIEWPORT, _NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW, _NET_WM_ACTION_ABOVE, _NET_WM_ACTION_BELOW, _NET_WM_STATE_STICKY, _NET_WM_FULLSCREEN_MONITORS, _NET_WM_STATE_FOCUSED, _NET_WM_BYPASS_COMPOSITOR, _NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION, _NET_WM_FRAME_DRAWN, _NET_WM_FRAME_TIMINGS, _NET_WM_WINDOW_OPACITY, _NET_RESTACK_WINDOW, _GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS, _GTK_SHOW_WINDOW_MENU, _GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS, _GTK_WORKAREAS
WM_ICON_SIZE(CARDINAL):
        minimum icon size: 32 by 32
        maximum icon size: 32 by 32
        incremental size change: 0 by 0
_GNOME_SESSION_RENDERER(STRING) = "GeForce GT 710/PCIe/SSE2"
_GNOME_MAX_SCREEN_SIZE(CARDINAL) = 16384
_GNOME_SESSION_ACCELERATED(CARDINAL) = 1
AT_SPI_BUS(STRING) = "unix:abstract=/tmp/dbus-VODphKjG09,guid=75eacb5b1c14c6407f8dcfcf5f357298"
GDK_VISUALS(INTEGER) = 43, 194
_XKB_RULES_NAMES(STRING) = "evdev", "pc105", "us,ru,ru", ",,", "nbsp:level3,grp:alt_shift_toggle,kpdl:dot,compose:ralt,lv3:ralt_switch"
XFree86_has_VT(INTEGER) = 1
XFree86_VT(INTEGER) = 2
```

В первых строчках можно получить доступную высоту 1053 и ширину 1920 отдельных экранов

_NET_WORKAREA - доступное пространство аналогичное wmctrl -d

---

Для с++ самый простой способ - это создать окно без рамки и maximized и получить от него размеры, но потребуется линковка на графическую библиотеку.

---

Но можно и подключиться к иксам через `XGetWindowProperty` - вот пример на c https://github.com/rdesktop/rdesktop/blob/1620a263bf710de951c3273ad07b5dff8f00c146/ewmhints.c#L134

---

Для Qt5

```
QRect rec = QApplication::desktop()->availableGeometry();
```

Comment: А в цэ++ как это сделать? Через `system`?

Comment: @dIm0n Дополнили ответ ссылкой на пример

Comment: @Mitski_fys какой-то граффической библиотекой пользуешься в проекте?

Comment: @eri Нет просто для самообучения заинтересовался такой задачей под линукс, и долго не мог прогуглить/найти ответ, который бы не предпологал использования Qt...

Answer (score 3):

`wmctrl -d` запрашивает свойство [`_NET_WORKAREA`](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html#idm46035372616560) через [ICCCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-Client_Communication_Conventions_Manual) у менеджера окон, реализующего спецификацию [NetWM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Window_Manager_Hints). На Си/плюсах это можно сделать как-то так:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/Intrinsic.h>

int main() {
  Display *dpy;
  
  dpy = XOpenDisplay("");

  Atom xaPropName=XInternAtom(dpy, "_NET_WORKAREA", False);
  assert (xaPropName!=None);

  Atom xaRetType;
  int retFormat;
  unsigned long rNItems;
  unsigned long bytesRemain;
  unsigned char *propData;

  int rc = XGetWindowProperty(
      /* display =              */ dpy,
      /* w =                    */ DefaultRootWindow(dpy),
      /* property =             */ xaPropName,
      /* long_offset =          */ 0,
      /* long_length =          */ 4,
      /* delete =               */ False,
      /* req_type =             */ XA_CARDINAL,
      /* actual_type_return =   */ &xaRetType,
      /* actual_format_return = */ &retFormat,
      /* nitems_return =        */ &rNItems,
      /* bytes_after_return =   */ &bytesRemain,
      /* prop_return =          */ &propData
      );
  assert(xaRetType == XA_CARDINAL);
  assert(rNItems == 4);
  assert (propData);
  if (rc!=Success) {
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  unsigned long *waGeometry = (unsigned long *)propData;

  printf("Work AreaGeometry: +%lu+%lu %lux%lu\n",
          waGeometry[0], waGeometry[1], waGeometry[2], waGeometry[3]);

  XFree (propData);
  return 0;
}
```

---

См. также документацию по [XInternAtom()](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XInternAtom.html) и [XGetWindowProperty()](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XGetWindowProperty.html).